# Read in different amount of columns ignoring specific elements in Python

Tags: python, text, multiple-columns

I am quite new to Python so please forgive my limited knowledge on the matter.

My task is to read each line from the following text file:

```
4   4738    6208    13891   14714
5   848 1184    3227    6539    7139
5   2748    8697    14917   15168   15751 
3   3568    10845   15435
4   5136    5460    12082   15854
4   3431    4571    10360   12118
0
3   1202    8022    13163
4   2510    2603    7023    8035
3   4886    7131    8428
5   1090    1091    2613    6863    14302  
3   7747    9374    11169
4   1360    2356    5122    11091
```

However, I'd like to ignore the first element of each row (namely all those 4s,5s,0, and 3s)and read in the rest, storing the numbers into an array.

I tried using the functions numpy.loadtxt, numpy.genfromtxt, but there seems to be a problem with the fact that the number of columns varies. I tried to optimize this by reading up to say, 10 columns and inserting an "N" when there is no number, but i'm wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing things.

Thanks

Blaise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you all the numbers (except the first column) in a jagged 2D list of lists of `int`s

```
with open('path/to/file') as infile:
    allNums = [[int(num) for num in line.strip().split()[1:]] for line in infile]
```

If you want to turn this into a non-jagged list of lists of `int`s, then:

```
import itertools
with open('path/to/file') as infile:
    allNums = [[int(num) for num in line.strip().split()[1:]] for line in infile]
nullValue = None
allNums = list(itertools.izip.from_iterable(allNums, fillvalue=None)) # python 2.x
# allNums = list(itertools.zip.from_iterable(allNums, fillvalue=None)) # python 3.x
```

Comment: @Jim: AFAIK, [`strip` kills all whitespace](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip)

Answer (score 0):

Read the whole line and then split based on the whitespace.  It should return a list of the correct size for each line. You will have to ignore the first element.